# Angular 8 Form Array

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

I got error `ERROR TypeError: "this.eventData.map is not a function"` 
when using form array. I don't have any idea how to fix it this error. This my code as you reference. I don't have any idea how to fix it this error. This my code as you reference. I don't have any idea how to fix it this error. This my code as you reference

**html**

```
<div class="card col-8 shadow-sm">
    <div class="list-group">
        <form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.valid && onSubmit()">
        <div class="list-group-item flex-column align-items-start" *ngFor="let list of eventData?.events; list as index; let i of index">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <h5 class="card-title pr-3 d-inline-block font-weight-bold">{{list.eventName}}</h5>
                <span class="border border-danger d-flex align-self-center pl-2 pr-2 text-danger">{{list.seats}} space left</span>
            </span>
                <span class="btn btn-primary btg" (click)="lightbox.open(0, 'lightbox',test)"><i class="fa fa-image pr-2"></i>Gallery</span>
            </div>
                <p class="card-text">
                    {{list.eventNote}}
                </p>
                <div>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold pr-2">Attendings :</span>
                    <span  class="ml-5">
                    <mat-radio-group [formControl]="myFormArray.at(i).get('attendings')"  aria-label="Select an option">
                        <mat-radio-button value="y">Yes</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button value="n">No</mat-radio-button>
                      </mat-radio-group>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-60 mt-4">
                    <div class="card  card-line col-md-12 mb-3" *ngFor="let fee of list.feeList; let i = index">
                         <div  class="card-body ctrl-height">
                         <input type="radio" [formControl]="myFormArray.at(i).get('confee')" id="{{fee.feeId}}" [value]="fee">
                         <label for="{{fee.feeId}}">
                          <span class="id-conf">{{fee.category}} {{i}}</span>
                          <span class="price">{{fee.price}}</span>
                        </label>
                        </div> 
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
     </div>
     <div class="card-footer no-gutters ctrl-lr">
        <div class="card-body float-right"> 
            {{form.value | json}}
            <a (click)="" class="btn btn-primary  card-link d-inline pl-4 pr-4">Submit </a>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

And this is Component Part

**Component**

```
    form = this.fb.group({
    attendings: new FormControl,
    confee: new FormControl

   });     

        ngOnInit() {
              this.getPackage(id);
            }

              getEvent(id){
        let t = 1;
        this.httpService.getConferenceEvent(t).subscribe(res =>{
            this.eventData = res;
            this.feeListData = res['feeList'];
            console.log(this.eventData);
            this.assignControls()
        })
      }


      assignControls(): void {
        this.controls = this.eventData.map(pack => {
            return new FormGroup({
                attendings: new FormControl(),
                fee: new FormControl()
            });
       })

       this.form = new FormGroup({
           formArray: new FormArray(this.eventData)
       });
    }
```

Hope you all can help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is getPackage being called?

Comment: ```getPackage``` is concurrent..... The rest of the code keeps running before ```eventData``` can be set. You need to set ```controls``` inside the ```subscribe``` or compose it in

Comment: @ukn it's at the top, in ```ngOnInit```

Answer (score 1):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` means this.eventData is undefined when the map is made. First you are calling your service but you are assigning your control to something that hasnt been initialized yet which is why its not working.

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this.getPackage(id);
    }

    getPackage(id){
        this.httpService.getPackageEvent(id).subscribe(res =>{
            this.eventData = res;
            this.assignControls()
        })
    }

    assignControls(): void {
        this.controls = this.eventData.map(pack => {
            return new FormGroup({
                attendings: new FormControl(),
                fee: new FormControl()
            });
       }
       this.form = new FormGroup({
           formArray: new FormArray(this.eventData)
       });
  });
```

Using that code, atleast the controls will be assigned when eventData exist. The error should disappear unless your service returns undefined or something that isnt an array.

To make it clear, when you subscribe to something, you are doing something asynchronous which means the code order doesnt mean anything. You either have to call functions from inside the subscribe or make the call synchronous by using await(don't do that, its bad since its going to freeze the app)

Comment: Thanks for you answer..But I got this error `core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: @Pravu is there a line number?

Comment: I edited my answer, I think the error you are getting come from the fact that eventData wasnt initialized while creating your formArray

Comment: it appear this `ERROR Error: "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });"`

Comment: Right now, angular tries to render the form but since its async, form isnt yet assigned to a formGroup so you either have to add an ngIf there <div class="list-group" *ngIf="form"> or initialize you form: form: FormGroup: new FormGroup({}); I could be wrong with the parameters of the initialization

Comment: @Pravu I think I answered your initial question, so you should accept the answer or edit your question!

Comment: You didnt do what I told you in my second last comment unless the code isnt showing everything or isnt updated

Comment: I think you should accept the answer(with the initial question) and open another question related to your form because its a completely different story.